# SSLSTREAM - An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the server

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, .net

i looked around a lot of similar question but none of this fixing my issue. We are upgrading to TLS 1.2 and am getting the below error which i got from Windows event log

**An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server.**

lantronix xport pro(Supporting TLS 1.2) Device making a call to the .net service deployed in Windows server 2012.

Client/Server Handshake is failing but am not able to figure out why. issue happens in the below line

```
stream.AuthenticateAsServer(_serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Ssl3| SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
```

Used Wireshark and Windows server 2012 R2 have only TLs 1.1 and 1.2 enabled using IIS Crypto

Client send TLS 1.2 Request with below Cipher suites

```
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_MD5 (0x0060)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA (0x0064)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003)
```

But server doesnt respond with Server Hello and finding the error message that none of the cipher supported by server.

I can see in IIS Crypto that AES_128_CBC_SHA in the crypto. But am not sure why it failing and almost stuck for days. Hope to get some clarity on what i can do further to troubleshoot this

**Update::**

I created a Client from Windows server 2012 and it is connected to the server and it is connecting TLS 1.2 with Cipher Suite: **TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)**

But when connecting lantronix xport pro(Supporting TLS 1.2)  server says 'The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm' on both X86 and x64.

Does it mean 2012 server does not support any of this ciphers sent by client

Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_MD5 (0x0060)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA (0x0064)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003)

**Server creating TCL SSLStream and not using IIS**

Any suggestion for this would be great

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated the firmware on the Xport Pro? That should be step 1.

Comment: A client supporting EXPORT ciphers (which are considered insecure for ages) looks like a severely broken client to me and I doubt that this device has proper support for TLS 1.2. The [specification](https://www.lantronix.com/products/xport-pro/#tab-features) only lists support for SSLv3 which sounds likely given the brokeness of the cipher suite.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes i did update  to the newest firmware. Is there any thing else i can do to confirm apart from the wireshark where am seeing TLS 1.2 request from client

Comment: @SteffenUllrich in Wireshark i can see TLS 1.2 and the listed ciphers  as per my question from the device . Still this could be wrong and broken ?

Comment: @Tharun: hard to tell without seeing the actual pcap. Apart from that, are you sure that the windows server is using an RSA and not an ECDSA certificate?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich am not 100% sure. Sharing the wireshark will help ? i can share a link uploading it?

Comment: @Tharun: sharing  a pcap (for example at cloudshark.org) might help to verify what the client is doing. It will not  help to check what certificates are installed at the server. To do this you might connect with a different client (like `openssl s_client` or a browser) to get and analyze the certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  thanks for the info i updated my question. Am facing problem when i deploy 64bit code. 32bit works fine. is this cipher not matching 64 bit?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  updated my question. Looks specific to 64 bit. is there something i can try ?

Answer (score 2):

Get the openssl client http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm to see how the cyphres are being called.

The command is openssl s_client -connect *website:port*

Most likely you might have NTLM pre authentication on your app, I would look into the providers for IIS and disable it. In the HTTP_REQUEST headers you should see something like:

*NTLM=*

Comment: Thanks for the update. am using SSL stream i just updated in the question as well. stream.AuthenticateAsServer is where am getting the exception